# Is it possible to add a reference in a C# project depending on the value of a conditional compilation symbol (preprocessor constant)?

Tags: c#, .net, reference, c-preprocessor, addition

I am developing a library which can be compiled for two different technologies. Basically, the users of the library should be able to compile the solution either for the [Unity3D](http://www.unity3d.com) game engine or the [NeoAxis](http://www.neoaxisgroup.com) game engine. The problem is: while the library is ready for the conditional compilation (#if UNITY using ... #endif, etc.), I can't find a way to enable a set of references or the other depending on the conditional compilation symbols.

Is it possible to do it? If so, how?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Yes but you have to do this in the msbuild .csproj file. This file is essentially just list of data, such as references.

What you do is add a [Condition](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/7szfhaft.aspx) statement to both References.

```
<Reference ..a.. Condition="'$LibToUse' =='NeoAxis'" />


<Reference ..b.. Condition="'$LibToUse' =='Unitv3D'" />
```

Then just define command line var called LibToUse with the desired value.

Answer (score 2):

How to add a reference by conditional compilation symbol only like you do in code. i.e. having or not having set for example UNITY in the project settings is answered in [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28387596/how-to-conditionally-reference-a-dll-based-on-a-compilation-symbol), and is simply done by editing your .csproj file, adding a Condition to the reference, and calling the **DefineConstants.Contains()** method like so:

```
<Reference Include="yourdll" Condition="$(DefineConstants.Contains('UNITY'))">
```

Answer (score 1):

Go ahead and add all the necessary references. They will automatically be removed by the compiler if never used in your code which will be the case thanks to the `#if/#endif`. Another possibility is to provide two different `.sln` files referencing two different `.csproj` files pointing to the same source code but different references. There are many projects doing this: `SomeProject_VS2008.sln` and `SomeProject_VS2010.sln`.

Comment: Using multiple csproj files violates the DRY principle, maintenance headaches galore https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Don%27t_repeat_yourself