# How to conditionally reference a DLL based on a compilation symbol?

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2013, csproj, compiler-directives

Visual Studio 2013.

I have an external DLL which I am referencing like this in the csproj file:

```
  <ItemGroup>
    <Reference Include="NameOfDll">
      <HintPath>Path\To\Dll\NameOfDll.dll</HintPath>
    </Reference>
```

I want this reference to function when a compiler symbol exists and to not function when that compiler symbol does not exist. (To address the first comment, below, let's say the compiler symbol is called Fred.)

This question
[ [Conditional Reference](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7798052/conditional-reference) ]
made me think I could add an attribute called Condition to the Reference element shown above but I can't work out what value to give that attribute to effect what I want.

I'd be most happy to be given a way to do this in the VS UI but I'll take any method.

Comment: @HansPassant Please assume the compiler symbol is called Fred if that helps you to understand the question. Is a compiler symbol a build property?

Comment: The conditional compiler symbols are in the DefineConstants build property. you'd check that DefineConstants contained some string in the condition. Something like `Condition="$(DefineConstants.Contains('Fred'))"`

Comment: @mikez Please give a little more detail in an answer and I'll mark it correct

Comment: Please could the close voter explain themselves

Answer (score 26, accepted):

The conditional compilation symbols are in the `DefineConstants` MSBuild property. Check that this contains your symbol:

```
<Reference Include="NameOfDll" Condition="$(DefineConstants.Contains('Fred'))">
  <HintPath>Path\To\Dll\NameOfDll.dll</HintPath>
</Reference>
```

Pick a distinctive name for the symbol. Not something that could be a substring of another constant like Debug or Trace.

Comment: Thank you for defying the negative first comment and the close vote